# find maximum in hash ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash

I've an hash array containing `value` and `field`. I am trying to find the **max** value out of that hash and associated field data.

Hash looks like this:

```
{0=>[[{"name"=>"Abc", "dbm"=>23}], [{"name"=>"dd", "value"=>8}], [{"name"=>"rr", "value"=>9}], [{"name"=>"sophia", "value"=>80}], [{"name"=>"guest", "value"=>45}] 1=> [[{"name"=>"gg", "value"=>67}], [{"name"=>"hia", "value"=>71}], [{"name"=>"oam", "value"=>45}], [{"name"=>"hh", "value"=>90}]]
```

I want to get both fields data which are `value` and `name` but only for **highest** value.

Example answer should be:

```
[0=> {"name" => "sophia", "value" = 90}
{1 =>"name" => "hh", "value" => 90}]
```

I tried this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8008468/how-to-find-the-key-of-the-largest-value-hash-ruby).
Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: "any suggestions" - Yes, you should use `max_by` as shown in that answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
array[0].max_by{|i| i[0]['value'].to_i}
```

Should work

Comment: only in some piece of `Rails`.

Comment: It's in ruby documentation: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-max

Comment: in pure Ruby `i[:value] != i["value"]`

Comment: @javiyu: Зелёный meant the difference between strings and symbols.

Comment: @Зелёный: no, this won't work even in rails (because those are plain hashes)

Comment: it is throwing error "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer:"

Comment: no it is not working still throwing error TypeError - no implicit conversion of String into Integer:

Comment: `[{"name"=>"Jorge", "value"=>56}, {"name"=>"sophia", "value"=>90} ,{"name"=>"Juan", "value"=> 78}, {"name"=>"Lor re", "value"=>67}, {"name"=>"Palua", "value"=>45},{"name"=>"Lau", "value"=>89},{"name"=>"SiSi", "value"=>69}].max_by{|i| i['value']}
 => {"name"=>"sophia", "value"=>90}`

Works for me, are you doing different?

Comment: yes, I am doing like this array[15].max_by{|i| i['value']}..is it the index of array that is the reason for this error..?

Comment: yes, you are referencing only one particular item in the array, try without the index

Comment: but I can not, I need the max value for each index...coz this array has and inside array for each index value

Comment: Can you post an example of your actual data structure?

Comment: Updated with example output

Comment: `array[0].max_by{|i| i[0]['value'].to_i}`

Comment: just last question, what is this i[0]? is it array index ?

Comment: yes, items in the hash are arrays with one element