# Find highest value from hash that contains "nil"

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash which looks like this

```
@hash = {
  0=>[{"name"=>"guest", "value"=>7.9}],
  1=>[nil], 2=>[nil], 3=>[nil], 4=>[nil], 5=>[nil], 6=>[nil], 7=>[nil], 8=>[nil],
  9=>[nil], 10=>[nil], 11=>[nil], 12=>[nil], 13=>[nil], 14=>[nil], 15=>[nil],
  16=>[nil], 17=>[nil], 18=>[nil],
  19=>[{"name"=>"test", "value"=>2.5}],
  20=>[{"name"=>"roam", "value"=>2.5}],
  21=>[{"name"=>"test2", "value"=>1.58}],
  22=>[{"name"=>"dff", "value"=>1.9}],
  23=>[{"name"=>"dddd", "value"=>3.16}]
}
```

I want the highest value from this hash in a variable. The output should be

```
@h = 7.9 \\only float value which should be highest among all
```

so I am doing like this

```
@hash.each do |k, v|
  if !v.nil?
    @h= [v.flatten.sort{ |v1, v2| v2['value'] <=> v1['value'] }.first['value']]
  end
end
```

but sometimes it works, and most of the times it doesn't.

Comment: You realise this is a strange data structure? Normally it would be an array, not a hash, if you are mapping all ints from 0 to N.

Comment: In future, try to trim you examples down to the bare essentials.  Here, for example, you could have reduced the number of key-value pairs in `@hash` to three or four (say, keys `0`, `1`, `19` and `21`), which would have made your example no less meaningful.

Comment: You [already asked a very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25723735/find-maximum-in-hash-ruby). As @mahemoff said, your data structure smells like you don't understand how to build the values, and, as a result, are having a hard time accessing them. Having multiple nil values is suspicious, and having all values being single element arrays is real suspicious. Perhaps asking a new question about how to create the hash would be good.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@hash.values.flatten.compact.map { |h| h["value"] }.max
=> 7.9
```

Which equates to:

- Get the values of the hash as an array
- Flatten all the elements in the values array
- Compact to remove all `nil` entries
- Map the remaining entries to the `["value"]` element in the hash
- Return the maximum of all those value

It makes a lot of assumptions about the format of your `@hash` though.

Comment: Nice solution, Shadwell.  `map { |h| h["value"] }.max` could alternatively be `max_by { |h| h["values"] }["value"]`, but I think `map/max` reads better.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer @Shadwell's solution, but here's another way:

```
hash.select { |_,v| v.first }
    .max_by { |_,v| v.first["value"] }
    .last
    .first["value"]
  #=> 7.9
```

The steps (with all but one `n=>[nil]` element removed for readabiity):

```
hash = { 0=>[{"name"=>"guest", "value"=>7.9}],
         1=>[nil],
        19=>[{"name"=>"test",  "value"=>2.5}],
        20=>[{"name"=>"roam",  "value"=>2.5}],
        21=>[{"name"=>"test2", "value"=>1.58}],
        22=>[{"name"=>"dff",   "value"=>1.9}],
        23=>[{"name"=>"dddd",  "value"=>3.16}]}

h = hash.select { |_,v| v.first }
  #=> { 0=>[{"name"=>"guest", "value"=>7.9}],
  #    19=>[{"name"=>"test",  "value"=>2.5}],
  #    20=>[{"name"=>"roam",  "value"=>2.5}],
  #    21=>[{"name"=>"test2", "value"=>1.58}],
  #    22=>[{"name"=>"dff",   "value"=>1.9}],
  #    23=>[{"name"=>"dddd",  "value"=>3.16}]}
a = h.max_by { |_,v| v.first["value"] }
  #=> [0, [{"name"=>"guest", "value"=>7.9}]]
b = a.last
  #=> [{"name"=>"guest", "value"=>7.9}]
b.first["value"] 
  #=> 7.9
```